# Understanding INSERT ... RETURNING

Tags: postgresql

Given:

```
$psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (12.1, server 9.6.2)

postgres=# \d foo
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           |          |
```

I then ran:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from foo;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

postgres=# insert into foo (a) values (1) returning (select count(*) from foo);
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

Why did it return `0` rather than `1`, i.e. since I inserted one row?

Comment: Do you want to count the rows in the table after the insert, or the number of rows that were inserted?

Comment: Count of rows after the insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select count(*) from foo` inside the returning clause is evaluated *before* the insert, and then treated as a constant in the returning clause, as `explain` clearly shows:

```
> explain insert into foo (a) values (1) returning (select count(*) from foo);
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                QUERY PLAN                                 │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Insert on foo  (cost=41.88..41.89 rows=1 width=4)                         │
│   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                 │
│     ->  Aggregate  (cost=41.88..41.88 rows=1 width=8)                     │
│           ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=0) │
│   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4)                            │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

This is confirmed by [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) where it says that the returning clause may contain *column names* or *value expressions (using those columns)* to be returned (saving a query after the insert):

```
> select count(*) from foo;
┌───────┐
│ count │
├───────┤
│     1 │
└───────┘
(1 row)

> insert into foo (a) values (1) returning 'a', a, (select count(*) from foo);
┌──────────┬───┬───────┐
│ ?column? │ a │ count │
├──────────┼───┼───────┤
│ a        │ 1 │     1 │
└──────────┴───┴───────┘
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```